# How to create a system call to clean page cache in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

**I want to know how to create a system call to clean page cache in Linux.**

It may not be the efficient way to clean page cache but I want to achieve this task by using a system call so how to do it?

Comment: Might want to look at the book [Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/pdf/understand.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

A decent answer was not given
when for research less than 5 minutes was required?
The sysctl.2 manual page explicates.
If the kernel is configured with CONFIG_SYSCTL_SYSCALL
then it may be possible, but the manual page indicates
that using /proc/sys/ interface is preferred.
Given the slowness of open and write close
the supposition that a syscall would be faster seems plausible.
But since it can and probably is disabled, oh well.
By the function posix_fadvise for one file descriptor at a time
the kernel cached blocks discard request can be made.
If already fsync ed then the kernel might comply.
It is related.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the kernel caches by doing `echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. Find out how this is implemented and then do the same thing in your system call. Read a tutorial on how to add a system call to Linux for details.

Comment: Any resource how echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches  is implemented ?

Comment: @TalhaA: "*Any resource how ...*" The Linux kernel sources?

Comment: @alk yes please specify where to find them

Comment: @TalhaA, [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) is the official place.  Your distribution should also provide a package or something with the exact source code used to compile the kernel that they ship.

Comment: Its very difficult to understand kernel source is there some other way to get to know how to implement this

Comment: @TalhaA Is it really that difficult to read one of the many "how to add a system call to Linux" tutorials? For `drop_caches`, try using `grep` in the kernel tree to find where this file is defined. If you want to do kernel program, you need to learn how to find such information on your own or it's going to be a very frustrating experience. Anyway, the implementation of the sysctl is in fs/drop_caches.c and the file system entry is created in kernel/sysctl.c. Thirty seconds of looking it up without any knowledge of how the kernel is structured.